# Write a char macro to a binary file

Tags: c, file

I've been working on some code that basically just tries to write a struct to a binary file in the form of a list, which isn't a problem, but I also need to write a macro at the end of every structure, the which is a char (I called it END_CHAR). What I use trying to do was:

```
#define END_CHAR 'F'
/*Some irrelevant code here*/
fwrite(&END_CHAR,sizeof(char),1,file_output);
```

I understand that this doesn't work because I'm asking the memory address of a char that isn't stored in any variable. So, what is the proper way to do what I want to do?

Comment: You're asking for the address of the number 70 -- that's not meaningful. If you actually want to put that number into a location and then take that address, you'll have to do something that allocates space (that is, make a variable or constant), then take its address.

Comment: `putc( END_CHAR, file_output);`

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up using this because I didn't want to create a new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `'F'` is just a way of writing the number 70 (assuming ASCII), so it's just a number, and you can't take the address of a number, only a variable. `#define` doesn't change that. So make a variable:

```
char endchar = 'F';

fwrite(&endchar, ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!